# PHP Get values from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am new to PHP and Arrays, I am trying to get the values from an array. But no matter how I'm trying to do it, I can't get the value. What am I doing wrong?

The Array:

```
Array ( [playerinfo] => Array ( [rank] => Godfather [cash] => € 8,520,530 [weapon] => M-16 (29000) [health] => Array ( [width] => 100 [color] => green ) [wealth] => Too rich to be true [protection] => Bulletproof Humvee [plf] => Huge [plane] => Concorde [crew] => None [pbf] => Large [ship] => None ) [character] => Array ( [crime] => Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 69 ) [gta] => Array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 70 ) [drugs] => Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 2528 ) [airport] => Array ( [0] => 2700 [1] => 2529 ) [oc] => Array ( [0] => 86400 [1] => 1442364 ) [tr] => Array ( [0] => 10800 [1] => 1640016011 ) [plf] => Array ( [0] => 7200 [1] => 6712 ) [kill] => Array ( [0] => 3600 [1] => 1640019611 ) ) )
```

The way I tried to get the info:

```
$AccData = json_decode($MobinfoString, true);
echo $AccData['playerinfo']['rank'].'<br/>';
echo $AccData['playerinfo']['cash'].'<br/>';

foreach ($AccData as $playerinfo) {
    echo $playerinfo['playerinfo']['rank'].'<br/>';
    echo $playerinfo['character']['gta'].'<br/>';
}
```

EDIT:

The json string

```
{"playerinfo":{"rank":"Boss","cash":"€ 5,923,712","weapon":"M-16 (4500)","health":{"width":"100","color":"green"},"wealth":"Too rich to be true","protection":"Bulletproof Humvee","plf":"Huge","plane":"Concorde","crew":"None","pbf":"Large","ship":"None"},"character":{"crime":[120,122],"gta":[400,369],"drugs":[120,2582],"airport":[2700,2582],"oc":[86400,1640020450],"tr":[10800,1640016850],"plf":[7200,3935],"kill":[3600,1640020450]}}
```

Anyone knows how to do this ? For example I need the Concorde from plane in a variable and the time values from gta in a variable. And some more from this string.

Comment: could you add json string too. and what do you expect to be printed.

Comment: Update my question, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried running `print_r($playerinfo);` inside the loop and see what that gives you.

Comment: I am searching for the logic to acces these ellements in the arrays. Any help is appreciated. Maybe a way to seperate the arrays from each other so I can acces them easyer?

Comment: I just run the given json with your very code, and it worked. `$AccData['playerinfo']['rank']` returns "Boss".

Comment: @Martin4523 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22c6255d4d87dbde7f9425ddda70d3fea59f4fea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your first Part is okay and you rank you can just display like the first part as well

```
$AccData = json_decode($MobinfoString, true);

echo $AccData['playerinfo']['rank'].'<br/>';
echo $AccData['playerinfo']['cash'].'<br/>';
echo $AccData['playerinfo']['rank'].'<br/>';
echo $AccData['playerinfo']['plane'].'<br/>';

echo $AccData['character']['gta'][0].'<br/>';
```

but the character is on the same level as playerinfo so you need to access it from AccData. also gta is an array like health, so you have to specify which value you want to show, the first so 0 or second which is 1

Comment: Verry strange. I have no results when I do the same. The json string you are using in the example sandbox has ‘ ‘ before and after the {}. My string doesnt as shown in the example. Could this be the problem?

Comment: no in PHP all text musst be inside '' if you dont see any result you have different array then you posted in the example.

please add

error_reporing(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors','On'); at the start of your file

or print_r($AccData);

Comment: No I have this array. It is coppied and pasted here. Hmm ill look into it later as i have no time now. Thank you so far !!